# Are internal combustion engine more efficient than steam turbines

Tags: energy, energy-efficiency, combustion

From what i understand the indicated thermal efficiency of an ic engine is measured at the fly wheel and is the measure of the amount of thermal energy being converted to mechanical energy please correct me if i am wrong
Soo
I came across this 2 stroke opposed piston engine (by achates power) which claims an indicated thermal efficiency of 51% to 52.4% and that is before exhaust heat recovery
So by assuming a modest heat recovery of even 5% to 8% ( of the available heat in the exhaust which often reaches temprature upwards of 400°c which should be relatively simple and we could go overkill with a supercritical CO2 turbine but let's just assume for now )
lets also assume that we won't be having any transmission losses by keeping it a direct drive and the generator efficiency to be 96% at converting mechanical to electrical power , still giving us a total system efficiency of more than >50% and a quick Google search of the efficiency of a typical thermal power plant is at best 48% (yes there are some record breaking power plants reaching efficiency upto 63% but i am referring to the majority)

So how is it that such huge power plants have Lower efficiencies than a ic engine? what's the deal why don't we use ic engine instead ( have i made any wrong assumption or was i just misinformed )

Comment: I don't know the numbers but my understanding is a steam turbine is far more efficient. My guess is that different efficiency metrics are being mixed and matched and not comparing apples to apples. Also, why do you refuse to use record-breaking power plant efficiencies in your comparison when you are using record breaking IC engine efficiencies? That's not a fair comparison. Most IC engines aren't anywhere near 50% efficient; More like 50% efficient.

Comment: Also, in terms of primary energy production, you want to take into account the energy used to refine the fuel. The power plant efficiencies given may not take these into account but are much more likely to whereas the IC engine efficiencies almost certainly do not. Another consideration is that it may be unfeasible to construct large piston engines (a large combustion engine involves more moving parts, large reciprocating masses, and are less reliable compared to turbines)

Comment: Powerplants should prefer to measure useful work at the electrical output...and assuming 96% there is overly optimistic.

Comment: It is not much good making claims without citing the sources.  And could you throw in a period, every now and then.  Make it random even!  Large marine engines use heat recovery to augment heating and electrical, but similarily they use the cheapest fuels, like crude and diesel.  So sources and clarification will help someone answer your question.